3 sets of wires, now what?
I removed an old medicine cabinet with a light fixture that I was surprised to find had an exposed and unsecured work box (maybe this is unsurprising to those who know what they’re doing; I thought it odd to find especially in a full bathroom).
Anyway, I was so disgusted with the dust and cobwebs that I neglected to take a decent picture of all the connections (facepalm).
I have three sets of wires, each with a black, white, and ground wire. I assume one goes to the switch, another to an outlet in another room, and one more to the breaker?
With a chicken stick I tested the wires with the breaker on and switch off. Only one black wire lit up. Does that reveal where that set of wires is coming from and then which should be capped together?



What is the second picture?

second pic is the medicine cabinet and fixture removed, new placement of wires, pre-patching of old hole

Thanks, all. I hired an electrician who used a multimeter to trace the wires appropriately.

You've found the "feed" pair.
Turn the breaker off and see if any of the (other) pairs of wires electrically connect together when you turn the switch on.
If so that is a switch loop and the white wire should have a prominent black or red marking on it (use tape or a sharpie etc)
the other pair probably goes to the light.
Connect them all in a ring  the whites for the feed and the light go together
the black of the light and the switch loop go together, and the white of the switch loop  (now coloured black or red) and the black of the feed go together.
If you don't find a switch loop just match all the colors up.

With the breaker on and switch on, the same black wire that was hot when the switch was off and breaker was on is still hot — and it is the only wire that is hot.
With the breaker off, none of the wires is hot.

You will have to use some other tool with the breaker off to detect connections the unpowered wires, continuity beeper, multimeter etc.

Thanks, all. I hired an electrician who used a multimeter to trace the wires appropriately.
